# Can I send mails with sensitivity 'personal' with MS Graph v1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there a way to set the "Sensitivity" when sending mails via Microsoft Graph API v1.0 ?
Microsoft allows to set Mail Sensitivity on Win-Outlook (Normal, Personal, Private, Confidential) and our end-users would like us to do the same through Graph API.

I noticed that simply prefixing the message subject with [PRIVATE] or [CONFIDENTIAL] persuades the MS Outlook clients on Macs and Windows that the message is private or confidential. However this does not work not for 'Personal' mails.
Is there a workaround for sending 'Personal' mails via Graph API?
Or possibly an official API - prefixing the subject feels like a workaround.

Comment: why this doesn't work for PERSONAL as you are just prefixing your subject?